# I wanted to create a custom field 'ParentId' but I got ParentId__c instead

Tags: custom-object, custom-field

I created a custom object. Then I created some custom fields. I have two types of custom objects:

```
Search

SearchResult
```

This is a one-to-many relationship. The `SearchResult` object should have a field "`ParentId`" that is the ID of the Search object.

Instead of `ParentId` I ended up with `ParentId__c`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is the ParentId__c the API name or the screen name. All custom fields are suffixed with __c in Salesforce on the API name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. All custom fields and objects automatically have __c appended to them. This way, there is never any conflict between a custom configuration and a standard object or field, even if the standard object or field is introduced after the custom objects and fields were created.